# Centre point of rotation of tiling in hyperbolic plane

Tags: riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, tiling

I'm reading this paper [On the Geometry of Hurwitz Surfaces](https://diginole.lib.fsu.edu/islandora/object/fsu:182653/datastream/PDF/download).
They define $T^{\pm}$ as the $(2,3,7)$ triangle group of $\mathbb{H}^2$ isometries generated by reflections and $T$ as the subgroup of $T^{\pm}$ of rotations.

At the top of page 12, it is stated

> "Clearly the only possibilities for such points (centre-points of rotations) are the face-centres, midpoints and vertices of triangles."

I can picture why this would be the case, but how would you prove that if the centre point is not one of these points, then the map does not preserve the tiling?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: consider the set of vertices that are the minimal distance from the centre of rotation. This set of vertices must be preserved (as a set) under a rotation that fixes the tiling.

Comment: Note that it is an odd thing to call $T$ "a subgroup of rotations" since it is merely generated by rotations (elliptic elements of the isometry group of the hyperbolic plane), but also contains elements which are not rotations (hyperbolic elements of the isometry group).

Comment: @MoisheKohan You're completely right, that was my poor wording. Thank you!